# Sending a HTML E-mail through outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

So i've prepared a simple accept/reject email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Accept or Reject</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table align="center">  
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="mailto:EMAILADD?subject=I%20Accept&body=I%20would%20like%20to%0D%0AAccept">
                    <input type="submit" value="Accept"> 
                    </input> 
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="mailto:EMAILADD?subject=I%20Reject&body=I%20would%20like%20to%0D%0AReject">
                    <input type="submit" value="Reject"> 
                    </input> 
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Issue i'm having is getting it to send in outlook.
I go to send a new e-mail > Attach file > (find html file) > Insert As Text.

Appears ok but when I send the e-mail is blank.

First time doing this would appreciate the help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I *think* Outlook strips form functionality out of html emails. Not sure, but I suspect it's some sort of security measure.

Comment: It's probably better/safer/simpler/more-widely-supported to provide a link to a browser page... or use the built-in functionality... http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/create-polls-in-e-mail-messages-and-review-the-results-HP010080425.aspx#BM1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both comments are correct - add some additional content to verify that this is the issue. Something like

```
<h2>Testing Email</h2>
```